# How to set the default option for SELECT Tag and how to get the Index of the selected option?

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, html-select

I would like to have a code in HTML and JavaScript that process SELECT and OPTION Elements

```
<select>
    <option>
    </option>
    <option>
    </option>
</select>
```

How I can get the Index of the selected option and then get the value of this index?

How can I make 2010 as the default option visual for users in the select tag existing in the form in a web page?

My code looks like that :

```
<select id="SelectYear" name="SelectYear" size="1">  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var startyear = "1950";
        var endyear   = "2020";
        for(var k=startyear; k<=endyear; k++ ) document.write("<option value="+k+">"+k+"</option>");
    </script>   
</select>
```

I tried many expressions to get that index even I know it may give a different thing like:

```
var vIndex = document.getElementById('SelectYear').selectedIndex;    
var vIndex = document.getElementById('SelectYear').selectedIndex.value;    
var vIndex = document.getElementById('SelectYear').selectedIndex.text;  
var vIndex = document.getElementById('SelectYear').options[document.getElementById('SelectYear').selectedIndex];  
var vIndex = document.getElementById('SelectYear').options[document.getElementById('SelectYear').selectedIndex].value;  
var vIndex = document.getElementById('SelectYear').options[document.getElementById('SelectYear').selectedIndex].text;
```

My workaround solution is to put the index static like:

```
document.getElementById('SelectYear').selectedIndex = 60 ;
```

But if I do not know the exact index or the index is changed according to the changes happended in the SELECT elements due to database update or manual edit?

Comment: please use the code block (ctrl+K) that we can read your question more easy...

Comment: I can see the question ans answers easily and the code is written in special color and surronded by squares what you mean by using Code Blocking ??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean, but it sounds like what you are looking for is simply: `document.getElementById('SelectYear').value=2010;`

Comment: I tried that but the displayed text for the selected option is not 2010 ! as you know value is stored behind and is not shown for the user and I want to change the default option in select element in case I do not know the index of it but I know the value and the text of it. I hope you get my point. Thanks for Comment ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="SelectYear" name="SelectYear" size="1">
<script type="text/javascript">
var startyear = "1950";
var endyear   = "2020";
for(var k=startyear; k<=endyear; k++ ) 
{
  var selected = (k==2010) ? 'selected' : '';
  document.write("<option value='"+k+"'"+selected+">"+k+"</option>");
}
</script>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you it seems the more related and working answer and I can change it to make it using the current date year ..

Answer (score 3):

To set the default option based on the index, try this:

```
select_element.options[the_index].defaultSelected = true;
```

(You may also have to set this property to false to the previous default option.)

Source: DOM 2 HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-37770574

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery would make this a fairly simple process.  Below assumes the select box has an id of SelectYear.

```
$('#SelectYear :selected').text(); //the display value
$('#SelectYear :selected').val(); // the actual value
```

Answer (score 1):

`selectedIndex` gives you the index of the option, thus a number between 0 and the total number of options. It's neither a object nor the id of the option.

```
var vSelect = document.getElementById('SelectYear')
var vIndex = vSelect.selectedIndex;
var vOption = vSelect.options[vIndex];

var vValue = vOption.value;
```

---

**EDIT:**

I think I'll just babble a bit about your code, because you seem to be doing several things wrong here. This may not be related to your problem, but maybe you are willing to learn something.

1) Having a `script` element inside a `select` element is invalid.

2) It seems that you are using the JavaScript-Loop to basically generate something that should be static. I would be much better to simply hard code the list of options in the HTML, or even better and if you want less work, generate it server-side.

3) You are speaking of the "default option", so you should also be doing that while generating the list, so either modify you JavaScript the way ajreal suggests, or, again better, directly give the option the `selected` attribute in your HTML, which is also possibe (again) server-side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes; I know the difference among the ELEMENT, THE INDEX, THE VALUE, THE TEXT but The problem is how to make a default option for the select combobox using the index ? do you get me ? as I wrote I mean how to make 2010 as default option in the select by knowing its index programmatically in JavaScript ?

Comment: It's really confusing what you want. Your text seems to contradict itself. You write you want to **get** the index, then you write you want to **set** the index, then you say you can't set the index because you don't have the index. I think you really need to simplify your question.

Comment: In other words, I have select tag with about 100 years. I know the text and value of every year but I do not know the index (I mean programmatically) and The displayed text for the selected option is not 2010 ! as you know value is stored behind and is not shown for the user and I want to change the default option in select element in case I do not know the index of it but I know the value and the text of it which is 2010. I know that 2010 has index of 60 in theory but how to do that in code ? I hope you get my point. Thanks for Comment

Answer (score 1):

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropDown');
for(var i = 0; i < dropDown.options.length; i++) {
    if(dropDown.options[i].text == 'value you want to set in drop down') {
     dropDown.selectedIndex = i; 
     break;
 }
```

Comment: Self-commenting code might be fine, but it is not entirely clear this actually achieves the OP's requirements. This is a **really old** question

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("country").value = "your index";
```

Answer (score 0):

A chunk of working code . It will show **orderDetails.type** you want to see as default and the list of options.

```
var selectOrderType = $("<select></select>").attr("id", "edit-orderTypes").attr("name", "orderType").attr('class', 'form-control');
var orderTypes = ['Samad', 'Said', 'Koksulton', 'Man'];
$.each(orderTypes, function (indexPrm, valPrm) {
    let flagLcl = false;
    if (orderDetails.type == valPrm) {
        flagLcl= true;
    }
    let anOptionLcl = new Option(valPrm, valPrm, flagLcl, flagLcl);
    selectOrderType.append(anOptionLcl);
});
```